# Ionic Side Menu under status bar

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want the Ionic Side-menu under the statusBar , like Gmail App.

[image]

Any suggestion ?

EDIT(1)

[image]

Comment: what you have achieved so far

Comment: It can be achieved or not?

Comment: Can you help me ? I can only change the color of the status bar

Comment: sure what have done so far

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110124/discussion-between-user5917414-and-mohan-gopi).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cordova-statusbar` plugin along with `Cordova translucent statusbar` plugin to enable the immersive mode on your apps. Refer this [article](http://www.martinadamko.sk/posts/translucent-bar-android-278) for step by step solution to this. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i don't want a fullScreen app, only the translucent statusBar

Comment: But it is the translucent bar shown in the link, with the status bar shown along with it

Comment: it worked, but now i can't set the "padding-top" on the header-bar

Comment: this code not work for me `.platform-android.has-translucent-status-bar.app-header-bar{ padding-top:255px!important;}`